# Как импортировать выборочные данные одного столбца в MySql?

Tags: sql, база-данных

**Дано.**
Есть таблица '**info**' в базе данных на 1000 строк. 
В ней есть столбцы: **info_id**, **info_text**, **info_date** (формат date) и тд.

**Задача.** 
В столбце **info_date** обновить часть значений значениями из эксель таблицы.

**Что я делаю.**

- Экспортирую всю таблицу **info** в формате "**csv**".
- Открываю данный файл в Google Doc (чтобы решить проблему кодировки UTF-8).
- Вставляю (ctrl + c - ctrl + v) в столбец **info_date** нужные значения дат. 
  Сохраняю обратно в "**csv**" файл.
- Затем в MySqL чищу таблицу **info** от данных и импортирую отредактированный файл "**csv**".

**В чем проблема.**
В столбце **info_date** после импорта таблицы вместо добавленных дат появляются нулевые значения (0000-00-00).

**Вопросы.**
1. Как вставлять данные чтобы сохранялся формат даты столбца в **"csv"** файле? (Если это вообще возможно).
2. Где почитать про перенос данных из эксель в базу данных?
3. Как еще можно перенести данные в пободном случае? Может через слияние таблиц запросом Sql? Подскажите, не могу разобраться.

P.S. По просьбе прикрепил скрин формат даты. 
[image: Формат даты - date]

Comment: а гляньте, в каком формате у вас дата в csv ?

Comment: Формат даты - Date

Comment: это в базе, а как выглядит дата в файле, который вы импортируете

Comment: Прикрепил скрин выше.

Answer (score 1):

у mysql есть функция str_to_date(string, format), а использовать ее при загрузке csv файла можно примерно так:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'имя_файла'
INTO TABLE mytable
(field1,@date,field3)
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%m/%d/%Y');
```